# least square solution of overdetermined system with additional unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I was hoping somebody could tell me the best way to solve the following overdetermined system for the scalars $x_{1}$,$x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$, where the C $3 \times 1$ vectors are unknown, $A_{i}$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $b_{i}$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector.

$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
A_{1} \\
A_{2} \\
A_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]=
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
C \\
C \\
C \\
\end{array}\right]-
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
b_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]
$

in a longer format this is written as

$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{1 \ 11} & \ldots &A_{1 \ 13} \\
\vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
A_{1 \ 31} & \ldots &A_{1 \ 33} \\
A_{2 \ 11} & \ldots &A_{2 \ 13} \\
\vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
A_{2 \ 31} & \ldots &A_{2 \ 33} \\
A_{3 \ 11} & \ldots &A_{3 \ 13} \\
\vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
A_{3 \ 31} & \ldots &A_{3 \ 33} \\
\end{array}\right]
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]=
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
C_{1} \\
C_{2} \\
C_{3} \\
C_{1}\\
C_{2} \\
C_{3} \\
C_{1} \\
C_{2} \\
C_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]-
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
b_{11} \\
b_{12} \\
b_{13} \\
b_{21} \\
b_{22} \\
b_{23} \\
b_{31} \\
b_{32} \\
b_{33} \\
\end{array}\right]
$

I have attempted to solve the equation by eliminating the constants so I end up with an equation as follows:

$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
A_{1} - A_{3}\\
A_{2}-A_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\end{array}\right]=
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
b_{3}- b_{1} \\
b_{3}- b_{2} \\
\end{array}\right]
$

from which I find the least squares solution for $x_{1}$,$x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$. Can anybody tell me if this is the correct way to the solution which minimizes the error?

Kind regards